# Why isn't the Tkinter Entry input reflecting on the sql table I connected it to? It is producing empty table records

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I created a database class whose instances should be sql tables. It has 3 methods: one that creates the table,

```
    def create_table(self, *args):
        c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {}  {} '''.format(self.table_name, args))
        conn.commit()
```

one that constructs the sql INSERT INTO statement,

```
    def insert_structure(self,mydict, table_name):
        query = 'INSERT INTO {} VALUES ({}{})'
        d = dict(mydict)
        y = next(iter(d))
        # table = d.pop(y)
        columns = ',:'.join(d.keys())
        placeholders = ','.join(['{}'] * len(d))
        values = d.values()
        f = str(query.format(table_name,':', columns, placeholders))
        return f
```

and one that is supposed to insert values into the table (using the insert_structure method).

```
    def insert_data(self,dicty, list):
        c.execute(self.insert_structure(dicty, self.table_name), dicty)
        conn.commit()
        for k in list:
            k.delete(0, END)
```

for the GUI I used tkinter so when I run the program a window with 4 entries and a button appears

The button takes insert_data as a command with the dictionary "dicto" as an argument (I use lambda so it is supposed to work).

```
dicto = {
                  'cow_id': cow_id.get(),
                  'lactation_phase': lactation_phase.get(),
                  'milk_production': milk_production.get(),
                  'weight': weight.get()
              }
entries = [cow_id, lactation_phase, milk_production, weight ]

cows.create_table('cow_id REAL', 'lactation_phase TEXT', 'milk_production REAL', 'weight REAL')
btn = Button(root, text = "Input cow's data", command = lambda : cows.insert_data(dicto, entries))
btn.place(x = 905, y = 350)
```

so when I click the button the values entered in the entries cow_id, lactation_phase, milk_production and weight should be inserted into the table I created but instead the values inserted are blank so each time I click the button it creates an empty record and I have no idea why is this happening.

Here's all the code:

```
import sqlite3
from tkinter import *
x = 0
root = Tk()
cow_id = Entry(root, width = 30)
cow_id.place(x= 340, y= 300 )
lactation_phase = Entry(root, width = 30)
lactation_phase.place(x = 525, y= 300)
milk_production = Entry(root, width = 30)
milk_production.place(x = 710, y = 300)
weight = Entry(root, width = 30)
weight.place(x= 895, y = 300)
cow_id_label = Label(root, text = "Cow Identification Number")
cow_id_label.place(x = 350, y= 270)
lactation_phase_label = Label(root, text= "Lactation phase")
lactation_phase_label.place(x= 545, y = 270)
milk_production_label = Label(root, text = "Milk production")
milk_production_label.place(x = 720, y = 270)
weight_label = Label(root, text = "Weight")
weight_label.place(x = 905, y = 270)
delete_label = Label(root, text = "To delete cow record enter cow ID" )
delete_label.place(x = 475, y = 500)
delete_entry = Entry(root)
delete_entry.place(x= 340, y = 500)
conn = sqlite3.connect("cows.db")
c = conn.cursor()

class databases:
    global c

    def __init__(self, table_name):
        self.table_name = table_name

    def insert_structure(self,mydict, table_name):
        query = 'INSERT INTO {} VALUES ({}{})'
        d = dict(mydict)
        y = next(iter(d))
        # table = d.pop(y)
        columns = ',:'.join(d.keys())
        placeholders = ','.join(['{}'] * len(d))
        values = d.values()
        f = str(query.format(table_name,':', columns, placeholders))
        return f
    def create_table(self, *args):
        c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {}  {} '''.format(self.table_name, args))
        conn.commit()
    def insert_data(self, dicty, list):
        c.execute(self.insert_structure(dicty, self.table_name), dicty)
        conn.commit()

        for k in list:
            k.delete(0, END)
        print(dicty)



    def delete_record(self, *args):
        c.execute('''DELETE FROM {} WHERE {} = {}'''.format(self.table_name, args))
        conn.commit()




cows = databases('cow')
dicto = {
                  'cow_id': cow_id.get(),
                  'lactation_phase': lactation_phase.get(),
                  'milk_production': milk_production.get(),
                  'weight': weight.get()
              }
entries = [cow_id, lactation_phase, milk_production, weight ]

cows.create_table('cow_id REAL', 'lactation_phase TEXT', 'milk_production REAL', 'weight REAL')
btn = Button(root, text = "Input cow's data", command = lambda : cows.insert_data(dicto, entries))
btn.place(x = 905, y = 350)
#btn2 = Button(root, text = "Delete", command = cows.delete_record)
#btn2.place(x = 670, y = 500 )
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this? For example, have you verified that the values immediately before the insert are what you expect them to be?

Comment: I did and the values aren't what I expect them to be (They're empty strings). The entry.get() is not returning user input and I don't know why is that

Comment: Then you can probably remove all of the sql code from the question, since the problem isn't with sql but rather with the code that is preparing the data.

Comment: I can't say if this has anything to do with your problem but `def insert_data(self, dicty, list):` ~ you definitely shouldn't be naming your list `list`.